# Does a Yeld spyrer's fly ability work just vertically, or on a hypotenuse?

Tags: necromunda

From the Yeld wings entry to the Necromunda rulebook (1st ed):

> The Yeld's wings allow its user to *fly* up to his normal Movement characteristic in a turn, or double that if he charges or runs (flaps). Since the Yeld's wings allow it to glide well rather than truly fly the Yeld must land at the end of his move. Flying upwards counts as 2" for every 1" moved; flying downwards counts as 1/2" for every 1" moved.

Now consider a Yeld on top of a building as in the diagram. He can either:

1. Fly vertically downwards, or
2. Fly along the hypotenuse

Clearly the distances are not the same.

[image: Yeld movement]

My question is, **which scenario is correct for the Yeld's movement?**

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking which scenario is possible, or are you asking what's the effective distance in both scenarios?

Comment: @ikegami: I am asking which scenario is possible.

Comment: So your question boils down to: *What's the maximum angle from the vertical at which you can sustain a glide?* I've never played the game, but the answer appears to be: As large as your remaining movement permits. Like you said, the distances are clearly not the same, and you are required to land by the end of your move.

Answer (score 1):

You measure from the base of your starting position to the base of where your movement ends. The movement must finish at an appropriate point (it cant be mid air for example). If that end point is higher than your starting point then its 2", if its lower its 1/2"

So for example, if you have movement 8, you have three options

1. Complete a move up to 4" ending above your starting position.
2. Complete a move up to 8" horizontally (normal move)
3. Complete a move up to 16" ending your movement below your starting position.

Comment: I don't know the game but that would be quite bizarre if you are right - you're saying that you can *not* move 15'' completely horizontally to the edge of a cliff, but you *can* move 15'' completely horizontally to the edge of a cliff as long as you proceed to then move one inch more to fall off the (very short) cliff.

Comment: No @BenjaminCosman only the movement while descending is halved. So you can go 8" towards the edge of the cliff one turn, then the remaining 7" the next turn, and a 2" glide forwards.

Comment: My comment wasn't "this is how it works", it was "this is how your answer says it works and that makes no sense". @Nick if you know how it *actually* works, please post a full answer of your own.